# Base de datos no me carga a phpmyadmin

Tags: base-de-datos

Amigos necesito ayuda los mas pronto posible
me sale un error al cargar base de datos

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'Rar!' en la linea 1

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Aug 18, 2016 at 12:39 AM
-- Server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-cll-lve
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `koe123_admin`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ads`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads` (
`ad_id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ad_title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`ad_content` text NOT NULL,
`ad_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ads`
--

INSERT INTO `ads` (`ad_id`, `ad_title`, `ad_content`, `ad_time`) VALUES
(2, 'Open ADS', '3 Days : $3 Credit<br>\r\n7 Days : $5 Credit<br>\r\n30 Days : $15 Credit<br>\r\n<br>\r\ninterest ? Contact Admin<br>\r\n<br>\r\n<br>\r\nRegards :<br>\r\nRPH Club<br>', 1421600321);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `api`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `api` (
`api` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`author` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`api`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bins`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bins` (
`card_bin` int(6) NOT NULL,
`card_bank` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`card_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`card_level` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`card_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`card_countrycode2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`card_countrycode3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`card_countrynumber` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`card_aci` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`card_bankphone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `bin` (`card_bin`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bins`
--

INSERT INTO `bins` (`card_bin`, `card_bank`, `card_type`, `card_level`, `card_country`, `card_countrycode2`, `card_countrycode3`, `card_countrynumber`, `card_aci`, `card_bankphone`) VALUES
(370247, 'INDUSTRIAL AND COMMERCIAL BANK OF CHINA', 'AMEX', 'PEONY EXPRESS', 'CHINA', 'CN', 'CHN', '156', 'CHINA, PEOPLES REP. OF', ''),
(370370, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370371, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370372, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370373, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370374, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370375, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370376, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370377, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370378, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(370379, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'PLATINUM', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(371000, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'GREEN', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(371001, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'GREEN', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(371002, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'GREEN', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
(371003, 'AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY', 'AMEX', 'GREEN', 'UNITED STATES', 'US', 'USA', '840', 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA', '800-528-4800'),
```

Comment: Quita todos los datos que esten entre `/**/` y también con `-` por ejemplo `-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump` quitalo!

Comment: tengo que borrar todo amigo por ejemplo --
-- Table structure for table `ads`
--

Comment: Si, solo son comentarios que se generan en el DUMP que no sirven de nada

Comment: sigo en las misma borre todos los comentarios y me sigue saliendo lo mismo  #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'Rar!' en la linea 1

Comment: Cambia esta linea en la creación de la primer tabla `CHARSET=latin1` por `CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: listo lo cambie pero sigue igual amigo :(

Comment: Que versión de Mysql tienes?

Comment: tengo xampp 7.2.5 la version del mysql no lo se

Comment: No veo problema en tu script, tendrás que hacerlo a mano. Uno a uno